# Can't get higher accuracy than 50%~ on CIFAR10 dataset

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to develop a CNN in TensorFlow for th Cifar10 dataset.

So far, I found the best setting for my CNN to be:

Conv1,patch 3x3,32 output
Max pooling 2x2
Conv2,patch 3x3,32 output
max pooling 2x2
Conv3, patch 3x3, 64 output
max pooling 2x2
Flat to array
Fully connected 1024 outputs
Softmax
Here is the code version:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 3, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 32])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 64])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)

h_flat1 = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1, 4 * 4 * 64])

W_fc1 = weight_variable([4 * 4 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_flat1, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
h_fc2 = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

I use RMSProp to minimize the cross entropy with a learning rate of 1e-4, batch size of 128, 500 epochs.I also normalized the images by subtracting the mean value, and shuffle the data at every epoch

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()


correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
i=0
j=0
offset=128
loop=int(50000/offset)
for k in range(500):
  i=0
  j=0
  datatotal,datalabel=unison_shuffled_copies(datatotal,datalabel)
  for j in range(loop):
    batch_xs = datatotal[i:i+offset]
    batch_ys = datalabel[i:i+offset]
    i=i+offset
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
  print(k,"test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: testdata, y_: testlabels}))
```

I have tried many different optimizers ( adam, adadelta, SGD, RMS ) and tried adding or removing various layers, including FC, dropout, and convolutional.

One of my best result is with the previous setup, which at about the 20th epoch gets stuck at 42% accuracy on the test data.

I even tried implementing the very same network found on this website: http://nghiaho.com/?p=1913 without having the same results.
Also tried implementing other networks from other websites, with also poor results.

How can I improve my results?

EDIT: Changed max pooling to average pooling,got 55% accuracy on 25th epoch. Better, but not quite right.

Comment: I assume that you did not perform a softmax operation before the call of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`. If so, you should definitely do a `tf.nn.softmax(y_conv)` before checking your prediction.

Comment: I didn't: here is the full code in case you want to check it out: https://pastebin.com/3Svyc7ze

Comment: I might miss something here, but the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` will perform a softmax before calculating the cross entropy, while the values you want to check for prediction do not have a softmax operation. I think you should replace `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))` by `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(y_conv),1), tf.argmax(y_,1))`, otherwise you won't be able to interpret it as probabilities. I don't know whether this will solve your problem, but it is probably necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still getting at best 62% accuracy ( I improved by tweaking the batch size ), but I agree your replacement make sense

Comment: Why not try a triplet network using a softmax triplet loss, like in this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6622.pdf 
You can find the softmax triplet loss implemented in tensorflow here: https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/tree/master/examples/SimilarityLearning
Using three convolutional networks with shared parameters really helps.